# Как сделать, чтоб срабатывала 2 исключения сразу?

Tags: ruby, исключения

Как сделать, чтоб срабатывала 2 исключения сразу, в чем у меня проблема, если первая исключения с работало, то второе исключения уже не работает.

```
 class Z<StandardError
end
class V<StandardError
end
def x(z)
 if z==12
  raise Z.new "z=#{z}"  
 end
 puts z
end
def si(t)
 if t==1
  raise V.new "x=#{t}"  
 end
 puts t
end

begin
 x(12)
 si(1)
rescue Z =>  zz
 puts "Fin #{zz}"
rescue V => ss
 puts "DELO #{ss}"  
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Механизм исключений отличается от механизма возврата (`return`) тем, что поднятое (`raise`) исключение (или иное значение) будет завершать не только контекст, в котором возникло, но и вызывающие контексты (дальше по стеку вызовов) до тех пор, пока не завершит контекст, в котором исключение ловится.

- У вас возникает исключение в `x`

  - в пределах метода `x` вы исключение не ловите

    - выполнение метода `x` обрывается, ничего не вернув
  - в пределах `begin`-блока в конце вы его всё-таки ловите

    - выполнение первой секции `begin`, всё равно обрывается и ничего не возвращает...
    - но после этого выполнится соответствующая `rescue`-секция, и её результат будет возвращён `begin`-блоком; пример:

      ```
      begin
        raise
      rescue StandardError
        :foo
      end
      # => :foo
      ```

Поскольку это игрушечный пример, назначение которого непонятно, конкретного способа починить этот код нет. Выполнить сразу несколько обработчиков исключений для одного контекста *в рамках одного вызова* нельзя. Ruby выбирает какой-то один и выполняет его; если исключение возникнет и там, управление покинет весь этот `begin`-блок (или для чего вы там разместите обработчик):

```
class A < StandardError; end
class B < StandardError; end

begin
  begin
    raise A    # пробуем попасть в rescue A
  rescue A
    raise B    # получилось; отсюда попробуем в rescue B
  rescue B
    p :success # не-а, сюда так и не пришли
  end
rescue StandardError => e
  e # смотрим возвращаемое значение
end
# => #<B: B>
# ошибка класса B внутри всё-таки не обработалась и вытекла наружу
```

---

#### Для интересующихся:

Совсем строго говоря, ловить исключения можно даже на уровне отдельных выражений, поэтому "обрывов" происходит несколько больше. Примеры ловли:

```
# Исключение можно было поймать и на уровне `if`:
if true
  raise
  puts "не выполняется"
end rescue :in_if # => :in_if

# И даже на уровне `raise`, хотя это видится мне бессмысленным
raise rescue :in_raise # => :in_raise
```

Скажем, иногда встречается идиома `опасный_метод! rescue nil` для подавления исключений и возврата "ничего" в качестве результата. Это плохая практика, но возможно и встречается.

Comment: Спасибо вам за доброту ! что хорошо так расписали